# Creating 4 mutexes based on 50 max processes, poor configuration?

Tags: php, mod-python

Looking at the Apache error log on my server this notice appears frequently each day

```
mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 50 max processes and 0 max threads.
```

Today for example, it has occurred **7 times** already between 23:59 and 09:35. Yesterday it was 15 for the whole day.

Apparently mutexes are used in mod_python for session locking, so I understand this will limit   the PHP requests to 4 per user. My website uses Ajax calls once per minute to update information so I understand this could be maxing out the sessions provided by server.

But my question is, ***why does this notice appear so frequently? Is it happening for each access by a unique IP per day, or is it a problem with the server trying to continually reconfigure itself?***

Comment: sorry is this PHP or Python related?